# best way of handling self-changing array of information

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This question is about handling arrays of information, there's are many ways I could do this, but I would like some input from programmers with more experience, I know what I want to do just not how to organize the information the best way, and objective-C is really making me ponder this, I don't want to get 100 hours into work a decide, oops this wasted the beast way to do this. So here goes:

I have a grid where I'm simulating a playing field, each piece of the grid I call a cell. The cells have around 20 different values each, all integers, nothing fancy. A change to a cell will be either by player input, or occur or by surrounding cells through different algorithms.

The changes to cells will occur once a turn is complete, so it's not real time. Now, I'm not even sure about doing this with a MutableArrays, a plain Array, or just a plain matrix. Arrays are good at keeping such info for one dimension, but I would imagine would become quite cumbersome if you have to address a batch of 10,000 of these cells. On the other hand a simple matrix might not be so elegant, but probably easier to work with.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here that I see:

1) Use standard containers

Assuming that the playing field is of constant size, then you can create a mutable array of x*y size, and populate it with mutable dictionaries. By giving everything in the second mutable dictionary keys, you can query and set their properties (all objects of course, so wrap ints in NSNumbers etc). For indexing use a macro INDEX_FROM_ROW_COL(row, col) and apply the appropriate code to multiply/add.

2) Create a helper object subclassed from NSObject. It would manage mutable objects as above, but you could load it with functionality specific to your application. You could provide methods that have parameters of "row:" and "col:". Methods that change or set properties of each cell based on some criteria. Personally, I think this is a better idea as you can incapsulate logic here and make the interface to it more high level. It will make it easier to log whats going on too.

Comment: Thanks! phew a lot of learning later and yeah, I've created a singleton with multiple mutable arrays holding integers. From the C/C++ world, mutable arrays seem like some serious boggy-running overhead, but after trying them out...whoa not at all, everything runs extremely fast even with more than 65000 cells, granted I know how to design fast code in the first place. I particularly like, and am taking advantage of the on-the-run resizing of arrays, can't do that with C/C++, at least in a practical manner. Now on to mutable dictionaries, again, thanks for the *pointers in the right direction.

Comment: If my answer works for you and helped, it's customary to click the checkbox that selects it (we all get points for doing that). If it really really helps you can hit the up arrow too (more points). Later on people judge helping people by the ratio of 'accepted' answers to their posted questions - people with close to 100% are much more likely to get help.